# How to transform Code to this RequestPurchase IdrequestPurchase = db.RequestPurchase.Find(id);

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

How to transform this

```
RequestPurchaseItem re = db.RequestPurchaseItem.Where(x=>x.RequestPurchaseNumber == id).ToList();
```

To  this

```
RequestPurchase IdrequestPurchase = db.RequestPurchase.Find(id);
```

Cause i need to like this

```
RequestPurchase IdrequestPurchase = db.RequestPurchase.Find(id);
```

i am very appreciate...thanks

Comment: Sorry We could not understand your question

Answer (score 0):

```
RequestPurchase IdrequestPurchase = db.RequestPurchase.ToList().Find(x=>x.RequestPurchaseNumber == id);
```